# Hyper-V virtualization with google compute engine image

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disk-image

I am trying to download an image from my Google Compute Engine VM Instances in Google Cloud Platform and I'm following this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) to export the image to a GCS Bucket and download it locally. I need to restore/import this image in an on-premises Hyper-V VM  for testing purposes.

How can I virtualize a Hyper-V VM from a GCE image?

Comment: Does it not boot already? What problem did you have when you tried it? If you did not try it, then you need to do that first, before posting here.

Comment: I download the image in RAW format but i dont know how to virtualize in HyperV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file you downloaded is a raw image of the virtual hard drive, then you will need to convert it to a VHD or VHDX first. The tools available in VirtualBox are a good fit for this situation.

```
VBoxManage.exe clonehd "diskimage.img" "diskimage.vhd" -format vhd
```

or

```
VBoxManage.exe clonehd "diskimage.img" "diskimage.vhdx" -format vhdx
```

Comment: I was under the impression that Hyper-V could use raw disk images directly? Is that not so?

Comment: You can use raw disks (aka a pass-through disk), but you can't use a raw disk image.

Comment: Well that's not very cash money...

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the image and i converted it with VBoxManage convertdd